# ExtJS custom bind

Tags: extjs, bind, viewmodel, extjs5

I have a form within a form. I need to bind the hidden property of a field in the outer form to the checked state of a field in the inner form. I assume I can do this with binding by setting up a custom getter/setter but not exactly sure... here's the idea:

[Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2626)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Ext.define('Test.InnerForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'innerform',

    defaultListenerScope: true,

    config: {
        isFoo: false  
    },

    twoWayBindable: {
        isFoo: true
    },
    publishes: ['isFoo'],

    items:[{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        fieldLabel:'cb',
        listeners: {
            change: 'onCheckChange'
        }
    }],

    onCheckChange: function(box, checked) {
        this.setIsFoo(checked);
    }
});

Ext.define('Test.OuterForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'outerform',
    viewModel: true,
    items:[{
        xtype:'innerform',
        reference: 'innerform'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'want to hide this when cb is checked',
        bind: {
            hidden: '{innerform.isFoo}'
        }
    }]
});


Ext.create('Test.OuterForm', {
    title: 'Outer form',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```